# MAUI: Change Label.Text using DisplayPromptAsync()

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I want to change the Content of a Label through the Pop-pup `DisplayPromptAsync()` which allows you to type text and save the text to use, but when I try to apply it does not work.

Label in XAML:

```xml
<Label Grid.Row="2" Text="UserName" x:Name="LabelName" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-45,0,0" FontSize="22"/>
```

Button in XAML:

```xml
<Button Grid.Column="1"  WidthRequest="115" HeightRequest="45" Text="Name" TextColor="White" Margin="200, 2 ,200, -274"  CornerRadius="19" Clicked="NameClicked"/>
```

Code-behind of Button:

```cs
private async void NameClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ResultName = await DisplayPromptAsync("Insira seu Nome", "Favor inserir seu Nome","Ok");

    LabelName.Text = ResultName;
}
```

I hoped that as soon as he kept the text in the variable could already assign and change quietly, only the code has no error is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a demo and here is the code in .xaml. It works well on my side.

```
<VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            
            <Label Text="UserName"  x:Name="LabelName" FontSize="22"/>

            <Button Clicked="NameClicked"/>

 </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Here is the code in .cs file.

```
private async void NameClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ResultName = await DisplayPromptAsync("Insira seu Nome", "Favor inserir seu Nome", "Ok");

        LabelName.Text = ResultName.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I thank you, I had done a conversion but it didn't work so I forgot to use a Simple ToString(); it's working perfectly, I appreciate it.